# jquery toggle show/hide

Tags: html, css

I've successfully implemented jQuery show/hide toddle on [my site](http://pligg.marsgibson.info/).

I want the image (plus-minus) to be located above (in other div) and show the requied toggle below at the same position

See this [screen shot](http://i49.tinypic.com/xlihr7.jpg)

Comment: It mostly relates to markup and styles than to JavaScript and jQuery.

Comment: Here is the jquery style and other details
http://tinypaste.com/05041221

Comment: Edited the question, this has nothing to do with jQuery and thus doesn't need any jQuery code.

Comment: Mate, consider adding cursor:pointer to the element which contains + and - image

Comment: I know it has to do with the style
what needs to do ?
style and html details here
http://tinypaste.com/05041221

Comment: maybe you could transfer .trigger p elements inside the .headline divs. or put a negative margin-top to the .trigger p elements.

Comment: Playmaker Can u plz elaborate more ?
cursor:pointer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

write like this:

```
.title h2 span, .title h2 a{
 vertical-align:top;
}
```

because **span** & **a** inside `.title` is `inline` element. So, give `vertical-align:top;` to it.

Comment: Thanks it solved the title alignment
now I also want the "Posted by richardtest (#4) 14 hours ago" to be slighty above
see the site again
http://pligg.marsgibson.info/

Comment: Its not working
also tell me how do I remove the gap between two stories ?

Comment: I removed the gap
but still want to move "posted by" slightly up
as in the following image
http://i49.tinypic.com/xlihr7.jpg

Comment: define display:block to your span write like this .subtext {
    display: block;
    font-size: 9px;
    margin-top: -10px;
}

Comment: Click the check button & it became green.